# Express Mongoose DB.once ('open') cannot execute a callback function

Tags: express, mongoose

```
exports.c_39 = function(req,res) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/cj');
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    console.log('a')
    db.once('open',function(){
        console.log('b')
    })
}
```

Can perform the console.log (' a '), but cannot perform DB.once ('open') callback function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because `mongoose.connection` isn't the same as the connection that is returned by `createConnection()`.

There are two ways of opening a connection with Mongoose:

```
// method 1: this sets 'mongoose.connection'
> var client = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
> console.log(client.connection === mongoose.connection)
true

// method 2: this *doesn't* set 'mongoose.connection'
> var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test');
> console.log(client.connection === mongoose.connection)
false
```

So to solve your problem, you need to connect your event handler to the connection as returned by `createConnection()`, and not to `mongoose.connection`:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/cj');
db.once('open', function() { ... });
```

In short:

- `.createConnection()` returns a `Connection` instance
- `.connect()` returns the global `mongoose` instance

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the difference between once and on in mongoose.connection.

Comment: @Alexander `once` will call the provided callback only one time, for the first `open` event that happens; `on` will call the provided callback _each time_ an `open` event occurs. See also the [events documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener) for Node.js

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mongoose.createConnection` use:
`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cj');`

Answer (score 0):

do

```
db=  mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/cj').
```

Then use

```
db.on("connected", connected); with connected = err => {
  console.log(`connected ${db.readyState}`);
};
```